# spring-data-mongo update null value in document with MappingMongoConverter

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

With spring data mongo, i need to update document in mongo.

My entity is define like this :

```
@Document(collection = "Orders")
public class Order{

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String clientContainerReference;
    private String status;
    private Bigdecimal amount;
    private BigDecimal remainingQuantity;
    ...
}
```

At first, this document is inserted in mongo with a remainingQuantity of 100. 
Next, the order is updated with a null remainingQuantity. 
After the update (upsert), the remainingQuantity is always set to 100.

This is due to the class :

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter
```

in the method writeInternal a null check is done on every property of the document. If the property is null, it is exclued from the generated DBObject.

```
entity.doWithProperties(new PropertyHandler<MongoPersistentProperty>() {
        public void doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentProperty prop) {

            if (prop.equals(idProperty)) {
                return;
            }

            Object propertyObj = wrapper.getProperty(prop);

            if (null != propertyObj) {

                if (!conversions.isSimpleType(propertyObj.getClass())) {
                    writePropertyInternal(propertyObj, dbo, prop);
                } else {
                    writeSimpleInternal(propertyObj, dbo, prop);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I can understand that it is more efficient because the generate DBObject is smaller and the update request is more digest for mongo. 
But how can i update real null values ?

More specific, in my case, all fields of all document could be null. so i doesn't want to write custom converter and map one by one each java field to DBObject Field.

For more my usecase, i have created a "NullAwareMappingMongoConverter" that override MappingMongoConverter to let the converter write the value if it is a null value.

```
entity.doWithProperties(new PropertyHandler<MongoPersistentProperty>() {
        public void doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentProperty prop) {

            if (prop.equals(idProperty)) {
                return;
            }


            Object propertyObj = wrapper.getProperty(prop);

            if (null != propertyObj) {

                if (!conversions.isSimpleType(propertyObj.getClass())) {
                    writePropertyInternal(propertyObj, dbo, prop);
                } else {
                    writeSimpleInternal(propertyObj, dbo, prop);
                }
            }
            else{
                writeSimpleInternal(propertyObj, dbo, prop);
            }
        }
    });
```

It's an very uggly solution, because, the MappingMongoConverter For spring data mongo has a package visibility. 
Does spring provide a way to tell : don't ignore null value on this properties with annotation or something else ?

Thank you

here is the code used to update the entity

```
 public T setNotificationDateAndSave(T entity) {
    Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null!");
    BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
    mongoTemplate.getConverter().write(entity, dbObject);

    DateTime expirationDate = getDeprecatedStatus().contains(getStatus(entity)) ?
            new DateTime().plusSeconds(EXPIRE_AFTER_SECONDS) : null;

    dbObject.put(EXPIRATION_DATE_COLUMN, mongoTemplate.getConverter()
            .convertToMongoType(expirationDate, ClassTypeInformation.from(DateTime.class)));


    NotificationDateUpdate update = new NotificationDateUpdate(dbObject, NOTIFICATION_DATE_COLUMN);
    Query q = Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(entity.getId()).andOperator(Criteria.where(REGISTER_DATE_COLUMN).lte(entity.getRegisterDate())));
    try{
        mongoTemplate.upsert(q, update, parameterClass);
    }catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
        logger.info(format("could not save notification : a more recent notification exists for collection %s and entity id : %s", parameterClass.getName(), entity.getId()));
    }
    return entity;
}
```

Comment: What's the code you're actually executing to update the document?

Comment: i put the update code at the end of my question

Comment: What's the reason you manually mess with the converter? What is `NotificationDateUpdate`?

Comment: Actually we are facing the same issue - there're some optional fields in out documents that may become null (i.e. should be removed from the document in db). Currently it's not possible and the only way to make it work is some ugly solution like overriding the MappingMongoConverter class :(

Comment: Btw, zouroto, did you consider the option when you get rid of the mongoTemplate at all and use the mongo client directly (converting pojos with the Jackson's ObjectMapper)?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem, but I didn't want to mess with the converter, it felt too complicated for the need. 
I simply automated the unsetting of all null fields for my object.

Slightly adapted to your code, it would look like:

```
DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
mongoTemplate.getConverter().write(entity, dbObject);
Update update = Update.fromDBObject(dbObject);
for (Field f : entity.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
  try {
     f.setAccessible(true);
     if (f.get(entity) == null)
        update.unset(f.getName());
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
ops.upsert(query,update);
```